# Launch facebook app ready to post

Tags: android, android-intent, android-facebook

How can I launch the facebook app from my app with already populated text for posting.

So far I have tried this

```
String uri = "facebook://facebook.com/post";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

But this just launches the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook doesn't allow pre-populated text for posting. See https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423/ . Also, I recommend you take a look at their new share dialog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/